# Google App Engine - keyword search + ordering on other properties

Tags: google-app-engine

Say I have an entity that looks a bit like this:

```
class MyEntity(db.Model):
    keywords            = db.StringListProperty()
    sortProp            = db.FloatProperty()
```

I have a filter that does a keyword search by doing this:

```
query = MyEntity.all()\
                .filter('keywords >=', unicode(kWord))\
                .filter('keywords <',  unicode(kWord) + u"\ufffd")\
                .order('keywords')
```

Which works great.  The issue I'm running into is that if I try to put an order on that using 'sortProp':

```
                .order('sortProp')
```

ordering has no effect.  I realize why - the documentation specifically says this is not possible and that sort order is ignored when using equality filters with a multi-valued property (from the Google docs):

> One important caveat is queries with both an equality filter and a
>   sort order on a multi-valued property. In those queries, the sort
>   order is disregarded. For single-valued properties, this is a simple
>   optimization. Every result would have the same value for the property,
>   so the results do not need to be sorted further. However, multi-valued
>   properties may have additional values. Since the sort order is
>   disregarded, the query results may be returned in a different order
>   than if the sort order were applied. (Restoring the dropped sort order
>   would be expensive and require extra indices, and this use case is
>   rare, so the query planner leaves it off.)

My question is: does anyone know of a good workaround for this?  Is there a better way to do a keyword search that circumvents this limitation?  I'd really like to combine using keywords with ordering for other properties.  The only solution I can think of is sorting the list after the query, but if I do that I lose the ability to offset into the query and I may not even get the results with the highest sort order if the data set is large.

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: If Full Text Search is what you are after, you might want to signup to the Truster Tester Program for the new api: https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEdWcnRJUXZ2VGR3YmVsT1Q1WVB2Smc6MQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing prefix matches, properly tokenize, stem and normalize your strings, and do equality comparisons on them.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround 1:
Apply stemming algorithms for keywords then you won't need to do a comparison look up.

Workaround 2:
Store all unique keywords in separate entity group ("table"). From this group find keywords which match your criteria. Then do query with `keywords IN [kw1, kw2, ...]`. Make sure that the number of matching keywords is not too big, for example you can select only first 10.

Workaround 3:
Reorder list of items on application side

Workaround 4: 
Use [IndexTank](http://indextank.com/) for full-text search, or apply for "Trusted Tester Program" as mentioned by @proppy.