# django-cms on google-app-engine (django-norel)

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel, django-cms

I'm trying to get the django-cms to work on google-app-engine. Did anyone succeed in getting such a beast to work?

I've got a sample django-norel app to work and deploy correctly, I've got the django-cms to locally crash in a bunch of absolutely cryptic ways.

```
DatabaseError at /
First ordering property must be the same as inequality filter property, if specified for this query; received site, expected publisher_state
```

Before I spend a lot of time trying to bughunt it, any success stories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error means that you have a query which has inequality filter on some field and ordering by another field. However this is not allowed on appengine's datastore (check the "Restrictions" section of [documentation on queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html)). And well [there is no easy way to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801508/google-app-engine-keyword-search-ordering-on-other-properties/8803820#8803820).

I have experience with both django and google-app-engine also I have worked with django-cms in the past. In my experience django was a very bad choice for appengine. Django-ORM is useless in appengine, the django-nonrell does not implement all functions of django-orm. As for django-cms I would not even consider to run it on appengine.

Comment: Do you know of any mature pythonic ORMs for GAE? We're slowly getting more request for 'cloud' based web-apps, vs our in-house Django/Memcached/PGSQL solutions.

Comment: Appengine's SDK already provides an object oriented interface to datastore. It gives you model definitions, polymorphic models, polymorphic queries, implementation of reference fields (the foreign-keys alternative). ORM is not quite a right word for it because the datastore is not a relational database.

Comment: I would recommend using a cloud provider that actually supports proper Django support, such as ep.io, gondor.io or heroku.com. django CMS does not and will not support GAE.